# difficulty in moving nav item and dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I designed a nav-bar having nav-items, drop-down button, the drop-down-menu 
items are not showing on display this is how it looks like

[image]

I have used margin-left to move sign-up nav-item thinking it'll move out but its not responding what other solutions can be proferred?? my code is...

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">       
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current) 
   </span></a> 
</li>
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us <span class="sr-only"> 
(current)</span></a>
</li> 
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us <span class="sr-only"> 
(current)</span></a>
</li>              
</ul>  
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign-Up</a>           
</li>
  dropdown menu 
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle " data- 
toggle="dropdown"> Log In <span class="caret"></span> </a>
<ul id="login" class="dropdown-menu">
<li>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12"> Log In Via:
<div class="social-buttons  d-flex flex-row">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa- 
facebook"aria-hidden="true">Facebook</i></a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter" 
aria-hidden="true">Twitter</i></a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-ins"><i class="fa fa- 
instagram" aria-hidden="true">Instagram</i></a>
</div>
</div>                                      
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please share the CSS for the affected part

Comment: The css                                                                                                      
    .navbar-light .navbar-brand{
    color: greenyellow;
    font-size: 22px;   
}                                                                                                                          
 .btn-secondary {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-right: 500px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute;
  }  .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu{
    position: absolute;
   
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Bootstrap helper class **dropdown-menu-right** like this:

`<ul id="login" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">`

Comment: Thanks... Drop down has moved to the right...